# Java class compile time error "Cannot access interface"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have an interface stores which has two methods getName() and getAddres(), and I have a class Market which implements Stores
This is my code:

```
public interface Stores {
    public String getName();
    public String getAddress();
}
```

And the concrete class:

```
public class Market implements Stores {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int size;

    public Market(String name, String address, int size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

I get errors in constructor regarding this.name=name, this.address=address and this.size=size saying that "Cannot access stores".
Any ideas why?

Comment: it probably can´t acces the `Stores` class because it doesn´t find it. Did you import `Stores` in the `Market` class?

Comment: @Kevin Those are in the same package, do I need to import Interface?

Comment: @KevinEsche And it doesn't give me any errors on the line public class Market implements Store

Comment: Try closing and reopening Eclipse.

Comment: if they are in the same package they shouldn´t, but the problem itself isn´t reproducable for me and everything should compile just fine. Are you using any `IDE`? If so i might restart the `IDE` or clean build the project

Comment: @LevonAsatryan You don't need to import it if its in same package. 
I copy pasted your code in some package and I have no errors there. So there must be something different in your code ...

Comment: @LevonAsatryan Depends on what editor you use but try to turn on/off it and refresh your project, its F5 in Eclipse on project.

Comment: It works perfectly for me.

Comment: @user1097772 I'm using IntellIJ Idea on linux mint, I turned off and restarted my PC. Same error.

Comment: @LevonAsatryan Well when I copy pasted your code you put there, I have no errors. So I suggest you do the same. Create some new package and just put there the code you put in your question. It should works fine. There would be probably some typo in the code in your editor or something like that.

Comment: Ok I found where I went wrong. When creating project, I added gradle repositories, and I just written my code in the wrong package.
Thank you @KevinEsche and others for your help :)
Cheers.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe you need to compile Stores.java? I would have thought the IDE would have done that automatically, though.

Answer (score 16):

It's 2020 and I'm still having this issue in IntelliJ Idea. Sometimes a restart of the IDE is enough but today I had to `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` in order for it to recognise a new interface that I had written. Refused to recognise it in package local as well as when explicitly `import`ed to other packages.

Comment: this worked for me on android studio 4.2 C15 SDK 30

Comment: Hey there I'm from 2021, I still have the same issue :/

Comment: from 2023 :(  and not a time travel.

Answer (score 10):

I've faced the same issue in Intetlij.
It was very weird for me what had helped:

I had to change any value in pom.xml (I've used "mainClass"). Then change it back (since value was correct). Project view was refreshed and class starts to see the interface.

Comment: Similar situation in IntelliJ I deleted unused maven auto created test classes and Rebuilt the project, worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this issue in IntelliJ multiple times. It clearly doesn't happen due to any compilation error in the code. And nothing seems to help, apart from killing the IDE and starting it again.

And I mean killing the IDE completely, and not closing and opening the project. After doing this, the error vanishes.

(I feel weird writing this as an answer, but happened too many times with me, that I know how such errors make you question what you know about programming. Hope no one else has to waste their time on this)

Answer (score 1):

- just restart intellij.

or:

- invalidat and rebuilt caches:

  file -> invalidate caches/restart -> invalidate and restart.

and it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IntelliJ.
My solution is quite simple. Go to the interface file, delete the word **interface** and enter it again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the problem directly with maven, on the command line.

The solution was twofold: update the compiler plugin (from 2.2 to 3.10), so it would complain correctly about the class file version (instead of just telling "cannot access"); and compile the dependency (containing the class that "cannot access") with the same java version (11 instead of 17) as the project that was giving the error, so they would have the same java version.